# Learn flow of a project to maintain

Tags: c#, xaml, workflow, project, windows-store-apps

I joined as a Fresher(trainee) in Software Company for Windows Store development. I don't know much about C#. My company is newly started Windows Store development. they don't have Dot net development before., that's why my company got an Senior dot net employee to complete the project,When ever he complete the project he left away from the company.
    My problem is I have to maintain the project after him. My question **how to manage a C# project**. How to maintain project if there is any issues. **I just want to learn the project flow & analyze my project to debug the project errors in future.** But i am struggling how to start to analyze the project

Don't neglect or close this question. I am not asking about my personal issue.
Please answer me how can i **start to learn & build my project regarding flow.** 
I can accept any suggestions & Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: What you want exactly want to learn c# ?

Comment: Here is a good article to get you started. There is a lot in there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1aa8f1.aspx

Comment: I think you should split your question up into smaller, more detailed pieces. So what actual tasks do you have? Automate build? Setup source-control? Do unit testing? Improve performance? Get a deeper understanding of Windows Store? From how I read your question, all of the above is a possible answer - and that is too broad to be likely to spawn good answers.

Comment: Try to ask exact problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn windows store apps then [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx) and [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/472009/Creating-Windows-Store-app-Beginners-tutorial) links will help you in beginner level

Its important to learn XAML or any tool which creates XAML for you like expression blend.Since maintenance changes will be more on UI side.

Comment: I know XAML well. Apart from this i am struggling with C# coding. I mean to say "some what i am new to c#". I am well versed with designing part of application(.XAML file) & then my issue is the C# code(.cs file). help me regarding code for c# in store apps.

Comment: Kumar C# will remain the same any way you can take a quick tutorial here http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorial.aspx. "Debug the code to understand more".There will be few concepts of linq and async programs in your code for those go through http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linqlist initially you might feel difficult but you will learn

Comment: For my project it is no need of Linq. it's a Windows store application for Windows Tablet, I will learn the tutorials. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Kumar If this answere helps you please make it as answer

Comment: It's my pleasure to do this. I just want to continue the discussion for me if there is any doubts ..